# AWS S3 HTTP POST - redirect to page with parameter in the URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have form that uploads to an image to S3, and it works perfectly fine. However, for the `success_action_redirect` key, I would like to have a URL that uses a template variable in the form, i.e.

```
{"success_action_redirect": "localhost/account/{{account.id}}"},
```

I can't seem to be able to use that in my post policy. Is there a way around it?

EDIT:

Here is the relevant line in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost:8000/account/{{account.id}}">
```

I'm assuming that it does not work because {{account.id}} returns a number, so when S3 tries to compare it with the signature, it's comparing something like `http://localhost:8000/accounts/2` with `http://localhost:8000/accounts/{{account.id}}"`.

It returns an error:

```
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$success_action_redirect", "http://localhost:8000/account/{{account.id}}"]
```

Furthermore, I tried using `{% templatetag %}` to stop `{{account.id}}` from being a variable, and though it went through to S3, it (obviously) didn't redirect to the correct page.

Comment: Have you tried creating a hidden form with the name of success_action_redirect  and the value with your required redirect_url? It should work actually.

Comment: Added more details in the question, but yes I have got a hidden input in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your policy you have to use `starts-with` and not `$eq` to allow for your success action redirect URL to match a prefix.

So your policy might look like:

```
["starts-with", "$success_action_redirect", "localhost/account/"],
```

See the Policy documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-ConditionMatching

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, even though I had used it for two of the other keys in the policy! Thank you so much :)

Comment: +1 for correct, but @monadoboi note that you can't trust this, because the account.id value is no longer constrained by the policy.  A malicious user can manipulate the HTML form before uploading the object.  Better to insert the desired literal value into both the policy (when generating the signature) and the form when you render it.  Never trust the user.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot account.id is a variable though. Having it as a literal value means have a different post policy/signature for every account. Are you implying that I should generate a new signature every time a user posts? Or is it just better to redirect to a page without a variable in the URL?

Comment: Yes, absolutely -- that's exactly what you should be doing: generate a new policy, signature, and form for each upload, setting the expiration time no longer than necessary.